# Loading Scala objects into RDD

Tags: apache-spark

A Scala class represents a `User`. The class has a companion object .

The class itself contains a `toXml()` function, and the companion object has a `fromXml()` function.

```
class User(val firstname:String, val lastname:String, val age:Int, val profession:String){
   def toXml(){...}
}
```

An XML file contains a list of users, as modelled by the Scala class.

A Spark RDD needs to be created\loaded from the XML file, so that it contains a collection of Scala objects of the type of our class, i.e. `RDD[User]`.

What is the best way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Did you tried creating your own RDD through AbstractJavaRDDLike and convert XML to Object in call function?

Comment: Can you show example data  and / or User class?

Comment: Edited the question to show a simple User class. The RDD would contain User instances, so it would be possible to, as a simple example, filter or all people with profession 'journalist' over 30 years of age.

Comment: Do you have a example of how to use AbstractJavaRDDLike? Thanks